# How do I send optional arguments to textFields on another screen using jetpack compose navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was trying to make a notes app with room database and dagger-hilt. Everything worked perfectly until i got to passing arguments from the home screen to the note screen using navigation in compose where the user can edit the text and update it. But for some reason, the arguments are not passed correctly into the textFields.

Thinking the problem was from room or hilt, i simplified the project by trying to pass two strings to two different textFields on the note screen but the problem persists. When i passed "note" and "content" to the two textFields on the note screen, the first textField which is supposed to get "note" just displays the default value from the navArgument in NavGraph and the second displays this {note_content}notecontent. it seems like the second texField gets both arguments. This is my code. pls help

Main Activity And Home Screen

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            NavigationTutsProjectTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    Navigation()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavController){
    val textTitle = "note"
    val textContent = "content"
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .clickable {
                navController.navigate(Screen.NoteScreen.route+textTitle+textContent)
            },
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = textTitle)
        Text(text = textContent)
    }
}
```

Routes for Home And NoteScreen with arguments

```
sealed class Screen(val route: String){
    object HomeScreen: Screen("home_screen")
    object NoteScreen: Screen("note_screen?note_title={note_title}&note_content={note_content}")
}
```

Navigation System

```
@Composable
fun Navigation(){
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screen.HomeScreen.route){
        composable(route = Screen.HomeScreen.route){
            HomeScreen(navController)
        }
        composable(
            route =Screen.NoteScreen.route,
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("note_title"){
                    type = NavType.StringType
                    defaultValue = "Nothing"
                },
                navArgument("note_title"){
                    type = NavType.StringType
                    defaultValue = "Nothing"
                }
            )
        ){entry->
            NoteScreen(
                noteTitle = entry.arguments?.getString("note_title"),
                noteContent = entry.arguments?.getString("note_content")
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Note Screen

```
@Composable
fun NoteScreen(
    noteTitle: String?,
    noteContent: String?
){
    var textFieldTitle by remember {
        mutableStateOf(noteTitle)
    }
    var textFieldContent by remember {
        mutableStateOf(noteContent)
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        textFieldTitle?.let {
            TextField(
                value = it, onValueChange = {it2->
                    textFieldTitle = it2
                }
            )
        }
        textFieldContent?.let {
            TextField(
                value = it, onValueChange = {it2->
                    textFieldContent = it2
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This is what i get when i run the code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqKNS.png)

Comment: Your code of `Screen.NoteScreen.route+textTitle+textContent` is just concatenating strings together. Were you expecting the `+` to replace `{note_title}` with your `textTitle` variable and `{note_content}` with your `textContent` variable? That's not what `+` does.

Comment: yes that's what i was trying to do. how do i get it to work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Screen.NoteScreen.route.replace("{note_title}",textTitle).replace("{note_content}" ,textContent)
```

instead of

```
Screen.NoteScreen.route+textTitle+textContent
```